# pandas dataframe self join with where condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Want to select few rows from a dataframe based on data in other rows.

Input dataframe

```
  user     event  time
0   u1       buy     1
1   u1  register     2
2   u2       buy     3
3   u1       buy     4
```

output expected dataframe (user with buy event who has registered before buy )

```
  user     event  time
3   u1       buy     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.merge(df, on='user', suffixes=('_x',''))\
  .query('time_x < time and event_x == "register"')\
  .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  user event  time
5   u1   buy     4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
out = (df.assign(event=df.event == "register")
         .groupby("user")
         .apply(lambda x: x[(~x.event) & (x.event.cumsum() > 0)])
         .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
         .assign(event="buy"))
```

We first binarize the `event` column s.t. `buy = 0, register = 1`. Then groupby over `user` and take the entries where `event` is `0` i.e. `buy` *and* already seen a `register` i.e. `cumsum > 0`. Then resetting index and assigning `event` back for exact output

to get

```
>>> out

  user event  time
3   u1   buy     4
```